# Validate input for html tags with asp.net mvc attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there an asp.net mvc attribute that would enable unobtrucive validation of my model's text fields for html tags in it?

Something like

```
[NoHtmlHere]
public string MyTextField {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net mvc should prevent html by default this protects against xss attacks.

To use the mvc validation you could use regex such as `<([a-z]+) *[^/]*?>`

```
[RegularExpression("<([a-z]+) *[^/]*?>", ErrorMessage = "This is html")]
```

Comment: Yes, it does, it throws an exception. What I want  is an attribute that would validate user input unobtrusively (with javasctipt) before the "submit" button is pressed. As an example - `[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]` attribute. 

For now I went with writing my own attribute, but I thought that there may be a built-in solution